# Problem related to composition of a function: $f^s(m)=tm$

Tags: number-theory, functions

Consider a pair of positive integers $(s,t)$.Does there exists a self map $f$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $f^s(n)=tn$ ,$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$?Here $f^s$ means composition of $f$ s times.

$\textbf{My Solution:}$

Let 'p' be a prime co-prime with t and 'a' be a natural number satisfying exactly one of the following three conditions

i) a is not a multiple of t nor a power of p

ii) $a=p^{bs}$,where $b\in \mathbb{N}_0$,$b\not\equiv0$ (mod t)

iii) $a=p^{bs+k}$,where $b\equiv0$(mod t),$0\leq k\leq s-1$ and $b\in \mathbb{N}_0$

We partition the natural numbers into three types and define a function $f$ as

i) $at^n ,n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and $f({at^n})=p^{as-1}t^n$

ii) $p^mt^n,n\in\mathbb{N}_0,m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m\not \equiv 0,1$(mod s) and $m\not\equiv 0$(mod t) and $f(p^mt^n)=p^{m-1}t^n$

iii) $p^mt^n,n\in\mathbb{N}_0,m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m\equiv 0$(mod s) and $m\not\equiv 0$(mod t) and $f(p^mt^n)=(\frac{m-1}{s}+1)t^{n+1}$

My question is can anyone find other functions satisfying the same property and even better is it possible to find all the functions that satisfy this property.

Also I shall be grateful if anyone can find any flaws in my function